# How can I make a test for this serialization that will fail when it's not incorporating all attributes?

Tags: python, json, unit-testing, class, serialization

I have the following class in Python 3.12.0:

```
class MyFile:
    def __init__(self,filepath: str):
        self._file_path = filepath
        self._file_size: str = None
        self._tags = set()
        self._collection:str = None
        self._file_hash: str = "" # Prob use SHA
        self._previous_filepaths = [] #Latest last
        self._device = ""


    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            "file_path": self._file_path,
            "file_size": self._file_size,
            "tags": list(self._tags),
            "collection": self._collection,
            "file_hash": self._file_hash,
            "previous_filepaths": self._previous_filepaths,
            "device": self._device

        }
```

The problem I am having is that if I go and add a new attribute to the class, like this:

```
class MyFile:
    def __init__(self,filepath: str):
        self._file_path = filepath
        self._file_size: str = None
        self._tags = set()
        self._NEW_ATTRIBUTE: str = None
        self._collection:str = None
        self._file_hash: str = "" # Prob use SHA
        self._previous_filepaths = [] #Latest last
        self._device = ""
```

When I run the program, the data will be prepared for serialization via `to_dict()` with the _NEW_ATTRIBUTE missing. This will silently cause the program to malfunction upon the next load because that attribute won't be deserialized and loaded into memory since it was never actually serialized in the first place.

How can I mitigate this issue? I thought of trying to write a unit test, but realized that if I do this, the same issue will occur because I would also forget to update the unit test with the new attribute. Is there some way to test whether or not the class attributes match some provided `to_dict()` method return?

PLEASE NOTE: This class does not have other complex class objects embedded, but I have other classes where for example, a class attribute is a list of other class objects, and so I don't think a simple `.__dict__` will work.

Comment: As an aside, everything is a "class object" in Python, which I surmise you mean "instance of a class".